# Delete Duplicate Record From BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have table which have column ID, which define unique records, all the rows having same ID are duplicate, I want to remove the duplicate rows and keeping only unique ID

```
ID Data
1   2
1   2
2   3
2   3
```

After Removal (My Data in BigQuery Table)

```
ID Data
1   2
2   3
```

I can create a new table having unique records only but is there any way I can update the existing table i.e remove the duplicate records from the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below ( all the rows having same ID are duplicate)

```
select as value any_value(t)
from `project.dataset.table` t
group by id
```

with output

[image]

In case , if definition of duplicate is - all the rows having all fields duplicate - consider below

```
select as value any_value(t)
from `project.dataset.table` t
group by format('%t', t)
```

Below is example of how to use it with DDL:

```
create or replace table `project.dataset.table` as 
select * from ( 
  select as value any_value(t)
  from `project.dataset.table` t
  group by format('%t', t)
);
```

Comment: I want to update the existing table and remove the duplicates, how to do that ?

Comment: you can use `create or replace table your_table as ...` with above provided select - right?

Comment: But that might be costly operation can we target only the duplicates ?

Comment: same cost as if you would do delete - but most importantly I doubt in your case delete is useful! also have in mind  - BQ is a columnar so cost is calculated not on rows amount but columns touched

Comment: can you give the example of delete in the same table it will be useful for me

Comment: i doubt you can easily (or at all) express your particular case with delete statement!

Comment: I getting this `CREATE TABLE AS SELECT AS [VALUE|STRUCT] is unsupported`
I have array elements in my schema I can't copy those ?

Comment: added example into answer